# Create a java process (daemon) in Web application Using Spring

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, spring-mvc, daemon, web-application-design

I have a requirement of creating a Java process daemon which will be residing in the same JVM  of Tomcat's container . The Daemon can be started by Trigger from application or can be started when the server is UP  and the daemon will be shut down once the server is DOWN .

I am referring this as a Daemon according to my knowledge but if there is any other way .

Also if there is any specific implementation provided by Spring .

Thanks in advance .

Regards,

Shahid